# z-index not working with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I opened the console (chrome\firefox) and ran the following lines:

```jquery
$("body").append("<div id=\"popupFrame\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;opacity:0.5;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;\" />");
$("body").append("<div id=\"popupContent\" style=\"width:200px;height:200px;z-index:1000;background-color:white;\" >dasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasd</div>");
```

The `#popupContent` should be above all but it's affected by the `#popupFrame` opacity.

The content is not contained in `#popupFrame` which makes this very weird.

The goal is to create a firefox-like alert box.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

The second div is `position: static` (the default) so the z-index does not apply to it.

You need to position (set the position property to anything other than `static`, you probably want `relative` in this case) anything you want to give a `z-index` to.

Answer (score 96):

Old question but this answer might help someone.

If you are trying to display the contents of the container outside of the boundaries of the container, make sure that it doesn't have `overflow:hidden`, otherwise anything outside of it will be cut off.

Answer (score 63):

Opacity changes the context of your z-index, as does the static positioning.  Either add opacity to the element that doesn't have it or remove it from the element that does.  You'll also have to either make both elements static positioned or specify relative or absolute position.  Here's some background on contexts: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Wow. According to the article, this includes opacity, "transforms, filters, css-regions, paged media, and possibly others."

Comment: Wow, didn't know this ! Really helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

`z-index` only applies to elements that have been given an explicit position. Add `position:relative` to #popupContent and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue a lot when using `position: absolute;`, I faced this issue by using `position: relative` in the child element. don't need to change `position: absolute` to `relative`, just need to add in the child element look into the beneath two examples:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle')

toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
 toggle.classList.toggle('change');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.change .slide {
  transform: translateX(33px);
}

.slide {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="toggle">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

## This's how it can be fixed using position relative:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle')

toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
 toggle.classList.toggle('change');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.change .slide {
  transform: translateX(33px);
}

.slide {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  
  // Just add position relative;
  position: relative;
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="toggle">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

## [Sandbox here](https://jsbin.com/guhunuwute/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

If you're a big 'ol dumdum like me (but know your positioning rules are 100% correct) trying to get something like this:

[image: undesired result]

to look like this:

[image]

Your solution may be as simple as ensuring your background is *not* transparent for the element you want in front of/behind the other element.

Answer (score 1):

I had the the same problem, and i tried to  solve it by `appending` the element with `absolute position` in a `div` with a `sticky position`, my problem was with speeddial (reactjs + material), so i dont know if it will work with all cases.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late, but it can be preferred as an alternative method. The order of layering for displaying elements in the absolute position depends on the order in which the elements are inserted into the parent element. In other words, instead of using z-index, it is possible to send it to the back by adding it with $(parent).prepend(me), and to bring it to the front by adding it with $(parent).append(me).

```js
function BringToFront(){
  $("#parent").append($("#me"));
}

function SendToBack(){
  $("#parent").prepend($("#me"));
}
```

```css
#mySister{
  position:absolute;
  left:25px;
  top:25px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#me{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#myBrother{
  position:absolute;
  left:75px;
  top:75px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">

  <div id="mySister">&nbsp;</div>

  <div id="me">Hello! this is me!</div>
  
  <div id="myBrother">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<button type="button" onclick="BringToFront()">Bring to front</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SendToBack()">Send to back</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the exact position.
i used `top: 0` and `right: 0`

```js
const para = document.createElement("div");
para.style.backgroundColor='black';

para.style.height='100%';

para.style.position='absolute'
para.id='newgrayscreen'
// Append to body:
function next(){
document.body.appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
#newgrayscreen{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5000009000;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<input type='button' onclick="next();" value="click to make a gray screen appear on top of everything" >
```