# Overlay div with transparent area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect on a webpage whereby I have a semi-transparent overlay over all elements on a page, except for one specific div.

This is an example of my page structure:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prprL/) of the above in action. I would like the *green* div (`#d3`) to be visible on top of the overlay.

Is there any way of achieving this without adding `position:absolute` to `#d3` or modifying the DOM? I am targeting the latest version of Chrome here and am open to Javascript/jQuery solutions if there is no pure-CSS3 solution available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `position: relative` for `#d3` for the `z-index` to work

```
#d3 {
    background: green;
    z-index: 9999999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WpK3L/)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute)

Comment: You should really be explaining why this works. Also, `z-index:1` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the [outline property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) is the simplest way to add an overlay around any element in CSS.

No need of z-index, just add the following code:

```
.myElement {
    outline: 99999px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

I created a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/xwP7X/).

Have a nice day,
Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

This is the explanation of why this works:  "The z-index will only work if the position property is set as well."

see http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspzindex.htm et.al.