# link (<a>) doesn't work with images in absolute position

Tags: html, css

The link line 44 works only when I remove 'position absolute' from my images. 
I tryed with opera, firefox, IE, safary and chrome.

I tryed to change z-index of my link whithout any result.

You can see this issue by downloading images and code there : 
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/kn6wdothgbsms/html_problem

I also copy/past you the code directly on this page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Document sans nom</title>

<style>

section>img:first-child
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; top:0;
}

section>img:nth-child(2)
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px; top:0;
}

article
{
    padding:50px;
}

a
{
    z-index:10;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

        <section>

            <img alt="article_end" src="main_top_left.png"/>
            <img alt="article_end" src="main_top_right.png"/>


            <article>
              <a href="www.google.fr">LINK</a> 
            </article>

        </section>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are looking to fix along with a valid problem.  Users should not have to download content in order to help you solve your problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also, `z-index` does not work on an element that has no css positioning.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Add a position to my link fixed the problem ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks Paulie for the link, I will examine it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index will only apply to elements that have been set `position: absolute` or `position: relative`; so in order to get your link "on top of" your images, you should give it a position: relative.

Working example: http://www.codeply.com/go/7Gog6kcwiC

See also [z-index not working with position absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute)