# How to adjust the z-index for two div

Tags: css

See the sample code here, without changing the html structure, is there a pure css way to re-order `#b` to shown in between `#a` and `#c`?

#### Question Update:

There is a condition that ***the `position` rule can not be change*** because of the UI restriction.

```css
#a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#c {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="c"></div>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index not working with position absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `#c` to be shown in the corner of the square, just give it a `z-index` of any number (ie `z-index: 30`). The `z-index` property allows you to change the stacking order of an element, so `#c` will now be in front of `#b` and `#a`.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
#a {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#b {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#c {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 30;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="c"></div>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `z-index:100;` for #b and `z-index:1000;` for #c

HTML part

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="c"></div>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

CSS Part

```
div {
  position: absolute;
}
#a {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#b {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#c {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```