# z-index with greater stack is not in front of the element?

Tags: jquery, css

The confusion I currently have is, that even though I set a greater z-index value for my div tag, after manipulating some CSS it is not on top anymore.

The code is use as follows:

```js
$('.lights').on('click',function(){
  $('<div id="lightsOut"></div>').appendTo('body');
  
  $('#lightsOut').css( { 
   opacity: 0, 
    width: $(document).width(), 
    height: $(document).height() 
  } )
    .addClass('lightsOut')
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    
  $('#media').css( { "z-index": "10000" } );
});
```

```css
.lightsOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h4>Title</h4>
<div id="media">
  <button class="lights">Lights Out</button>
  <h4 style="color: grey">Another Title</h4>
</div>
</body>
```

When the "div media"-element is clicked, I would like to change the background to black while still displaying the "div media"-element. How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index not working with position absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a positoin relative

```
$('#media').css( { "position": "relative" } );
```

Snippet below

```js
$('.lights').on('click',function(){
  $('<div id="lightsOut"></div>').appendTo('body');
  
  $('#lightsOut').css( { 
   opacity: 0, 
    width: $(document).width(), 
    height: $(document).height() 
  } )
    .addClass('lightsOut')
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    
  $('#media').css( { "z-index": "10000" } );
    $('#media').css( { "position": "relative" } );
});
```

```css
.lightsOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h4>Title</h4>
<div id="media">
  <button class="lights">Lights Out</button>
  <h4 style="color: grey">Another Title</h4>
</div>
</body>
```