# Z-index with absolute positioned parent

Tags: html, css, z-index

I need the `:before` element to appear under the parent element, but it does not work. Below is my CSS, and you can find a working example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanc/1ejg4kwa/).

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
.element:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: you may get down votes for this type of question. Give your complete code, Or make a working fiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute

Comment: your fiddle makes no sense, why would you want to draw smaller square under the big one and make it invisible? Don't you need 2 div elements?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 It just a scratch, that explaining more clear what i need. I can`t show you real example. With 2 div i can do it by my own. But my task is to make it just with element and before pseudo element...

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a child tag in your container.

The problem is that `:before` inherits z-index from its parent. `z-index` works like layers, everything in your `.element` will have a `z-index: 10`, and can only be indexed with elements in the same 'layer'.
I hope I'm clear enough.

```css
.element{
  position: relative;
}

.element .child {
  position: relative;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  z-index:10;
}

.element:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `:before` i've created two seperate div's. see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ejg4kwa/4/) Or the code snippet down below:

```css
.element-1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  z-index:10;
}
.element-2{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-1">
  
</div>
<div class="element-2">
  
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works but i need inherited element not neighbor. But thanks that you try to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your task is unachievable (i guess) if parent object has:

```
position: absolute;
```

removing it solves the problem (if removing it is allowed).