# Text is not showing over background

Tags: css

My h1 header is not showing above the background that I created I don't know why its happening. https://jsfiddle.net/b6gezctv/ Here is a jsfiddle so you will be able to run the code and see if it gets fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head>
  <title>Coming Soon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soon.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" 
  rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="heading">
    <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
      <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="start-1"></div>
  <div class="start-2"></div>
  <div class="start-3"></div>

</body>
```

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.start-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #202b36;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 950px;
}

.start-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(https://server.pro/s/img/bg-pattern.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.07;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 950px;
}

.start-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: 
 url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2821/33503322524_4e67143f45_k.jpg);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  min-width: 950px;
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of the problem but you've also got a closing HTML tag right after your opening tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `start-1` `start-2` `start-3` elements are `position: absolute` and they are covering your `h1`. You will need to add a `position` and `z-index` to your `h1` so it can be visible:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```

Or, since you have an `hr` inside your `heading` class, I would suggest adding the `position` and `z-index` to the entire class, rather than just the `h1` element

```
.heading {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: and, as I wrote in my answer ,you still won't see the h1 since it has white text color on a white background, so change either text color or background.

Comment: Adding position: relative did the trick for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS parameter The font-color (`color`) of your `h1` is white, and since you don't have a background for the body or any parent element of that `h1`, it displays white on white = invisible.

So either change the background or change the font color.

In addition, your other elements have `position: absolute`and position `left:` and `top: 0`, so they are covering that `h1` change those position values, or delete that `position: absolute` from the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently z-index is not applicable to static positioned elements, so just add position: relative to h1 styling and it will work, like below:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

Related question: [z-index not working with position absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute)