# Positioning an absolute element above other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am building this frontendmentor site and im having trouble positioning the shopping cart div on top of the rest of the elements. At first i tried using z-index but apparently that doesnt work with elements that have a position style. I used position relative on the parent and absolute on the child so it would always appear under the shopping cart icon. Is there any other way to force an element on top or should i change the way i position the div.

```css
.right-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.account-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-icon-container {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.cart-icon-container img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.shopping-cart-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  right: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.185);
}

.shopping-cart-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-container">
  <div class="account-container">
    <div class="shopping-cart-overlay">
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">
        <h4>Cart</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="shopping-cart-content">
        <p>Your cart is empty</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/index.html" class="cart-icon-container">
      <img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart">
    </a>
    <img class="avatar" src="./images/image-avatar.png" alt="profile-pic">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values) --> "_**absolute**: This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto_" - Look at this diagram and read [the accompanying text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#the_example) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it does work. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483589/z-index-not-working-with-position-absolute/14483631) to get a better understanding of how `z-index` works with `position`. You just couldn't notice it because the `div` was transparent.

Check out the snippet below. It's your exact code, but I changed the `background` and positioned the `.shopping-cart-overlay` element closer to the other elements, just to show you that it actually works.

```css
.right-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.account-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-icon-container {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.cart-icon-container img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.shopping-cart-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 5rem;
  //right: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.185);
  
  /* Changes */
  top: 0;
  left: 125px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: red;
}

.shopping-cart-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-container">
    <div class="account-container">
      <div class="shopping-cart-overlay">
        <div class="shopping-cart-header">
          <h4>Cart</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="shopping-cart-content">
          <p>Your cart is empty</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/index.html" class="cart-icon-container">
        <img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart">
      </a>
      <img class="avatar" src="./images/image-avatar.png" alt="profile-pic">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i am so glad u found that out gues i read about that wrong xD

Comment: Sure. Mark it as the correct answer pls. Thanks.